# How can I decrypt my iphones nand flash memory if I have the pin but phone won't turn on?

Tags: memory, iphone, flash

Is there some sort of device I can plug my nand flash chip into and then input my pin and get my old notes and things back?

Comment: Not really. You have the NAND flash memory chip nicely desoldered? You could try a flash memory chip reader like the TopMaxII. But it's going to be a pain in the butt. You could also try soldering the chip onto a phone of the same type that does turn on. But, probably you want to just send it to a data recovery lab. You can google for one.

Comment: Oh okay. It's getting really hard these days to fix your own stuff and more expensive to get them fixed sadly.

Comment: yup it sure is...

Comment: Isn't the encryption key stored separately from the flash chip?

Comment: there could be many reasons the phone won't turn on. fix the phone, then export the data.

Comment: Well I thought it was the battery, so i replaced the battery. Then when I went to apple to try and get a replacement phone they said what most likely happened is the battery bubbled and caused a buildup of co2 and probably shorted out something on the mainboard. Who knows, I just bought a samsung galaxy s4 instead for 60 bucks. All these phones are designed to break within a few years so I''m not going to waste my money.